# Flutter: Reschedule notification on reboot (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-local-notification

Hey guys quick question regarding rebooting on android:
I have an app that is supposed to schedule reminders. When I reboot my device, those notifications aren't scheduled anymore so I have to reschedule them. So I wrote a function for rescheduling . I am using the alarm manager plus with the bootListener to trigger a callback on restart. What do I have to consider to successfully callback on reboot?

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
import 'package:project_h2o/services/notification_service.dart';

Future<void> setupBootListener() async {
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

  // Set the delay to a minimum value as we only need to trigger the callback
  await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
    Duration(seconds: 1), // Minimal delay
    0, // Unique identifier for the alarm
    notificationService.rescheduleNotifications,
    wakeup: true,
    rescheduleOnReboot: true,
  );
}
```

And in my main I call the setup

```
void main() async {
  await initializeDateFormatting();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await findSystemLocale();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('Europe/Berlin'));
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.initNotifications();
  await setupBootListener();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you looked at this, but I had a similar problem. You need to go into the AndroidManifest.xml to write a few lines for the alarm manager to work and be able to be there on reboot

Look at this link in the get started section to do that

[Android alarm manager plus documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus)